# Parse text files to database using python

Tags: python, database, text

I've been trying to work out how to parse a set of text files to a database.  The files look like this:

```
[STATION NUMBER]
2001
[END]
[AM Details]
Year Type,Water Year,Oct
[End]
[AM Rejected]
1974,1974
[END]
[AM Values]
01 Apr 1975,  120.209,    2.150
06 Jan 1976,  158.699,    2.470
21 Jan 1977,  128.289,    2.220
23 Feb 1978,  198.254,    2.770
[END]
```

I want to get the second line "2001" as the key for each line under "[AM Values]".  I've worked out how to separate the values from the 'tags' (i.e. [STATION NUMBER], [AM Details] etc)  but not how to separate the data into columns.  Here's the code I've got so far:

```
import os
import os.path
import csv
import re
from zipfile import ZipFile
from itertools import islice

#Extracts and loads the files in a zip file to a specified destination
ze = ZipFile(open("/Users/jem/WINFAP-FEH_v3.3.4.zip","r"))
ze.extractall("/Users/jem/WINFAP-FEH_v4.1/")
print "Extraction successful"


#Meta data of the zipfile
zf = ZipFile('/Users/jem/WINFAP-FEH_v3.3.4.zip', 'r')
zc = zf.namelist()
#print zc

data = []
#Loop to run each csv file and print the data
if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    while i < len(zc):
            for csv_path in zc:
                if os.path.splitext(zc[i])[1] == ".AM":#make sure it's an annual maximum file
                    os.chdir('/Users/jem/WINFAP-FEH_v4.1/')
                
                    with open(zc[i], 'r') as input_data:
                        for line in input_data:
                            if line.strip() == "[AM Values]":
                                break
                    
                        for line in input_data:
                            if line.strip() == "[END]":
                            break
                            print line
                
                    #for row in csv_f:
                        #print row
                    input_data.close()
                    i += 1
                else:
                    i+=1
print(data)
```

The files are in a zip that's publicly available to download (here: http://nrfa.ceh.ac.uk/sites/default/files/WINFAP-FEH_v4.1.zip) and is updated infrequently, which is why I want the capacity to read from the zip file directly.

I noticed I got a -1 vote for no apparent reason so I thought I'd clarify.  I'm not asking someone to write the code for me. I don't need to know how to open or connect to a database, I can work that out.  I don't need to know how to get values into a list.  I think I need to find out how to break a line from a text file into columns (then I'll replace the 'print line' statement).

I know it's against the rules to ask for opinions, but if you think I've done this all back to front then, y'know, feel free to tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you what the end result to look like? it's unclear how you want it formatted. Also, it's worth including what you've attempted to get this to work (so, the output you're currently getting and how it differs from what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need for one line of data:

```
>>> line = '''01 Apr 1975,  120.209,    2.150'''
>>> [_.strip() for _ in line.split(',')]
['01 Apr 1975', '120.209', '2.150']
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll give it a try.